# Finding strings with a specific number of letters, extensions included with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep, glob, ls

If I pipe `ls` to `grep`, how would I be able to return a list of files with the condition that they only have an x amount of letters, extension included?

So for example, if `ls` gives me:

```
abcde.jav a156e.exc test.c prog1.c qwert r.c
```

and I'm looking for all files that contain strictly 5 letters, extensions included:

```
a156e.exc test.c prog1.c qwert
```

I've tried:

```
ls | grep '^[a-z]${5}'
ls | grep "^[a-z]|[a-z]$"
```

and other things like that, but I can't seem to get it. It seems like the solution should be really simple but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Aside: If you happen to do so: Do not use `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. *Globs* are much more simple AND correct: 
Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: `qwerty` has 6 letters. That shouldn't match, right?

Comment: You can use `find` instead of `ls`.

Comment: @JoshCrozier, you're right, my mistake.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein, I had no idea! I appreciate the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

**[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/qW1aP7/1)**

```
^([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*){5}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Anchor denoting the start of the string
- `([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*)` - Group that matches a single letter between zero or more non-letter characters
- `{5}` - Match the previous group 5 times
- `$` - Anchor denoting the end of the string.

Usage:

```
ls | grep -E '^([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*){5}$'
```

Or without `ls`:

```
for f in *; do
  if [[ $f =~ ^([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*){5}$ ]]
    then
      echo $f
  fi
done
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Great regex. You can avoid `ls` without resorting to a (slow) loop: `printf '%s\n' * |  grep -E '^([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*){5}$'`. Or, using a process substitution: `grep -E '^([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*){5}$' <(printf '%s\n' *)`. (This would still break with filenames with embedded newlines; with _GNU_ `grep`, this could be remedied as follows: `grep -zoE '^([^a-z]*[a-z][^a-z]*){5}$' <(printf '%s\0' *)`).